# single-line "braided" concatenation in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there any single-line code out there that can give this exact behavior? that is, take two strings and return a "braided" concatenation of sorts, assuming both strings are of the same length?

```
string1 = '01234'
string2 = '56789'

output = '0516273849'
```

Comment: Btw, this is commonly referred to as "interleaving". That word might help you find answers. And don't strive for single-line solutions. Have you managed to solve this by any means yet?

Comment: thank you for giving me the common name for this. i have most certainly solved my problem now... my earlier attempts were much too convoluted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this way (without using `join` and `for`):

```
output = list(sum(zip(string1, string2),()))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: brilliant! i'll be using this way, definitely.

Comment: Glad you like it! Please **Accept** the answer if you see it is the one you are after.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) followed by string concatenation in a list comprehension:

```
string1 = '01234'
string2 = '56789'

output = ''.join([x + y for x, y in zip(string1, string2)])
print(output) # 0516273849
```

Comment: are there any possible optimizations if i wish for the output to be a list of the form ['0', '5', '1', '6', '2', '7', '3', '8', '4', '9'] ?

Comment: @RohanCurran You omit the `join` (which is used to convert the list to a string). So simply `output = [x + y for x, y in zip(string1, string2)]` should give you the list.

Comment: this actually yields `['05', '16', '27', '38', '49']`... i solved it by using `output = list(''.join(x+y for x,y in zip(s1,s2)))` instead. thank you for your help!

Comment: @RohanCurran Good catch :)